# Not able to convert response into array

Tags: php

I created an API that sends A data string to a remote API and get response. The data string I am sending is

```
$data_string = '{"listings":[{"title":"B","city":"xyz","available_date":"2013-06-25 00:00:00"}]}';

$datas = http_build_query(json_decode($data_string,true));
```

Then I sent this `$datas` string using curl request and got the following response:

```
{:response=>[{:status=>"error", :errors=>"You already have a entry with this city", :data=>{"title"=>"B","status"=>"STATUS_ACTIVE", "created_by"=>"import", "available_type"=>"Date", "source"=>"API"}}]}
```

Now I am not able to convert this response into array.

Comment: `:errors=>"You already have a entry with this city` try with a different city name

Comment: Why bother with creating a JSON string (`$data_string`) and then decoding it; just create an array

Comment: Also, what is the response content type meant to be? It's certainly not JSON. What service are you sending the data string to?

Comment: your JSON response not in correct format

Comment: I'm guessing this is for https://showmojo.com/

Comment: I was asked to use http_build_query(json_decode($data_string,true)) to send data string by the remote API developer. The success response is also in the same format. Is there any way to convert it into array?

Comment: Looks like the service returns a Ruby object literal. What headers are you sending (you can omit your auth token)? You should probably follow the documentation - https://showmojo.com/ShowMojo_Listing_Import_API.pdf. The examples there look good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you don't have control over the response. If you do, you should make it into valid JSON before sending it.

Assuming you don't have control over the response, you need to turn it into JSON, because that's what it is trying (and failing) to be. Then you can parse it.

Try something like this:

```
$response = '{:response=>[{:status=>"error", :errors=>"You already have a entry with this city", :data=>{"title"=>"B","status"=>"STATUS_ACTIVE", "created_by"=>"import", "available_type"=>"Date", "available_date"=>Mon, 19 Aug 2013, "source"=>"API"}}]}';
$response= preg_replace(array('/=>([^"]+?)(, ?"|\})/', '/[": ]*([^:="]+)"?=>/', '/", "/'), array('=>"$1"$2', '"$1":', '","'), $response);
$response = json_decode($response);
var_dump($response);
```

This does the following:

- Replace anything starting with `"`, `:`, or a space, then a string of characters followed by `=>`, with a quoted version of the string. So, `:status=>` becomes `"status":`. We remove extra spaces between elements at the same time. This makes it proper JSON.
- Use `json_decode()` to parse the JSON.

Voila, you have an object containing your data, like this:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["response"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
      ["status"]=>
      string(5) "error"
      ["errors"]=>
      string(39) "You already have a entry with this city"
      ["data"]=>
      object(stdClass)#3 (6) {
        ["title"]=>
        string(1) "B"
        ["status"]=>
        string(13) "STATUS_ACTIVE"
        ["created_by"]=>
        string(6) "import"
        ["available_type"]=>
        string(4) "Date"
        ["available_date"]=>
        string(16) "Mon, 19 Aug 2013"
        ["source"]=>
        string(3) "API"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can access it with, for example, `$response->response[0]->errors`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. You are a Savior.

Comment: Just one more thing i want to ask. If i send some more parameters and get "available_date"=>Mon, 19 Aug 2013,  in response


$response = '{:response=>[{:status=>"error", :errors=>"You already have a entry with this city", :data=>{"title"=>"B","status"=>"STATUS_ACTIVE", "created_by"=>"import", "available_type"=>"Date", "available_date"=>Mon, 19 Aug 2013, "source"=>"API"}}]}';

then it creates problem in converting.

Comment: Wow, that is one busted API. See my edit, which addresses this as well. Please remember to select an answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it in this way :

```
  $str  = '{:response=>[{:status=>"error", :errors=>"You already have a entry with this city", :data=>{"title"=>"B","status"=>"STATUS_ACTIVE", "created_by"=>"import", "available_type"=>"Date", "source"=>"API"}}]}';
  $str  = str_replace(":", "", $str);
  $str  = str_replace("=>", ":", $str); 

  $str = str_replace(array("\n","\r"),"",$str);
  $str = preg_replace('/([{,]+)(\s*)([^"]+?)\s*:/','$1"$3":',$str);
  $str  = (array)json_decode($str);  
  print_r($str);
```

Answer (score -2):

I suggest not to use this

```
$datas = http_build_query(json_decode($data_string,true));
```

just keep this:

```
echo $data_string;
```

to return the response from api call do the following:

```
$data = json_decode('Your cURL response'); // this becomes an object.
```

I have built an api, you can use this one https://github.com/busfirms/api